# Why $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(1+\cfrac1x\right)^x=+\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

According to plot of [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2B1%2Fx%29%5Ex), $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(1+\cfrac1x\right)^x=+\infty$

But I am confused because when I am calculating the limit I get $1$:

$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(1+\cfrac1x\right)^x=\lim_{x\to 0^-}e^{x\ln\left(1+\tfrac1x\right)}$

$\lim_{x\to 0^-} x\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\cfrac{\ln(1+\tfrac1x)}{\tfrac1x}$ Apply L'Hopital rule: $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\cfrac{\tfrac{x}{x+1}\times\tfrac{-1}{x^2}}{\tfrac{-1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{x}{x+1}=0$

Therefore the original limit is equal to $1$. but according to plot of the function $\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$ it should be $+\infty$.but why?

Comment: [WolframAlpha yields $\large\color{red}{1}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%281+%2B+1%2Fx%29%5Ex%2C+x+-%3E+0%2C+Direction+-%3E+%22FromBelow%22%5D) and ${\tt Mathematica}$ too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to 0^-}$ does not make sense here. For $-1 < x < 0$ we have $b_x = 1 + \frac{1}{x} < 0$ and thus $(1 + \frac{1}{x})^x$ is not defined. In Wolfram you see that $\lim_{x \to -1^-}(1 + \frac{1}{x})^x = \infty$.

Comment: Oh I got it. but why for ${b_x}^x$ Where $b_x<0$ it is undefined ?

Comment: If you want, you can define it for some $x$ (rational $x$ with odd denominator), but not for all of these $x$. Take e.g. $x = -2^{-n}$. Also your approach using $\ln b_x$ does not work.